# TensorFlow py_function nested output type?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is it possible to specify a nested output type for TensorFlows's [`py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function)?

As a specific case, I would like to have the `py_function` have a return type of `((tf.float32, tf.float32), (tf.float32, tf.float32))`, where the individual elements are not necessarily of the same dimensions. Is there a way to specify this for `py_function`?

Just as some insight into why this is useful in my case, I have a `tf.data.Dataset` with lists of file paths. The `py_function` takes one of those file paths and from the file, generates a negative and positive example along with corresponding labels, resulting the `((positive_data, positive_label), (negative_data, negative_label))` (note, the labels are not necessarily single values, but they are also not the same shape as the input data). This `py_function` can be mapped to the dataset and (with the above structure) have one level flattened to produce a training dataset with `(data, label)` structured elements. While it's possible to have a workaround where the data and label are stacked in the `py_function` and later unstacked (or start completely unstructured from the py_function and only paired afterward), it's leads to a messy and confusing setup. If the `py_function` could directly output the `((tf.float32, tf.float32), (tf.float32, tf.float32))` type, it would result in a cleaner setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output type of `tf.py_function` cannot be a nested sequence. When using a `tf.py_function` with the `tf.data` API, however, you need to create a wrapper function (`tf_foo` in the example below), and you can nest the outputs in that  function.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# The python function.
def foo(x):
    return x, x, x, x

# Wrap the python function to make it compatible with `tf.data.Dataset.map`.
def tf_foo(x):
    a, b, c, d = tf.py_function(foo, [x], Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32])
    return (a, b), (c, d)

dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
dset.map(tf_foo)
# <MapDataset shapes: ((<unknown>, <unknown>), (<unknown>, <unknown>)),
#  types: ((tf.float32, tf.float32), (tf.float32, tf.float32))>
```

This is also demonstrated in a [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#applying_arbitrary_python_logic).